# Paid Ether to ICO but tx failed, however the Ether is not returning to my wallet!

Tags: transactions, wallets, ico, etherscan

Earlier today I have made an ether payment to an ICO, due to I just updated my ethereum address on that ICO web page, it wasn't updated correctly on their database, hence when I sent the ether it failed :

Ether transaction: [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x9bc0350ae021363e9cf666b3530656568456274532f9370410c1ca41c74f194a)

Block information: [here](https://etherscan.io/block/4650058)

This is the first time I send ether and it gone missing now. Hope you experts can help!

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of wallet are you using (ie from an exchange, from an online wallet, your own node)?

Comment: I'm using Exodus desktop wallet.

Comment: From the etherscan.io page your funds were returned to your account, it seems Exodus didn't understand the transaction was reversed, perhaps you should contact their support so they can fix it. If you have the private key of your account, you can use another wallet to access the full amount.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've only ever had **three** transactions. Two debiting your account and one crediting.

`7.06 - 1.001565608 - 0.0004895(gas used from failed transaction) = 6.057944892`

Your account balance at the minute is: `6.057944892`

To me it doesn't look like you've lost any Ether according to your account data. With the exception of the gas used from failed transaction of course.

> UPDATE: Seems like Exodus wallet didn't register that transaction failed until 15+ hours later. Issue resolved and funds now showing in wallet.

Comment: Hi Malone, but my birthday sorus wallet only shown 3.xx ether balance, the 3 ether I sent that was cancellled doesn't seems to come back to my wallet.

Comment: The etherscan blockchain explorer is more accurate.

Comment: the ether is back to my exodus wallet already... it takes15-18 hours to return.

Comment: @justinheng good stuff! can you please mark your question as answered? - I've updated the answer to contain more info about exodus.